# Linking error 4.3 ios

Tags: xcode, linker

Just updated from xcode 4.1 to 4.3 because I needed some functions. But now one of my old programs is not working any more. It is not complex and didn't require and additional frameworks in xcode 4.1

Here's my error:

```
Ld "/Users/rickvugts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myappname-gzvclbdfiudwvlbjjxtyfixndpkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxx.app/xxxx" normal i386
    cd "/Users/xxxx/Documents/Development/Mobile/xxxx/v2"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
-L/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myappname-gzvclbdfiudwvlbjjxtyfixndpkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myappname-gzvclbdfiudwvlbjjxtyfixndpkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-filelist "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myappname-gzvclbdfiudwvlbjjxtyfixndpkd/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxr.build/Objects-normal/i386/xxxx.LinkFileList"
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myappname-gzvclbdfiudwvlbjjxtyfixndpkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.app/xxxx"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_gGeboorteDatum", referenced from:
      -[myappnameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in myappnameAppDelegate.o
      -[myappnameAppDelegate dealloc] in myappnameAppDelegate.o
      -[myappnameViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in myappnameViewController.o
      -[myResults viewDidLoad] in myResults.o
      -[myappnameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in myappnameAppDelegate.o
      -[myappnameAppDelegate dealloc] in myappnameAppDelegate.o
      -[myappnameViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in myappnameViewController.o
      -[myResults viewDidLoad] in myResults.o
      -[myappnameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in myappnameAppDelegate.o
      -[myappnameAppDelegate dealloc] in myappnameAppDelegate.o
      -[myappnameViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in myappnameViewController.o
      -[myResults viewDidLoad] in myResults.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

-----



"_gGeboorteDatum", referenced from:

-[myappnameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in myappnameAppDelegate.o

-[myappnameAppDelegate dealloc] in myappnameAppDelegate.o

-[myappnameViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in myappnameViewController.o

-[myResults viewDidLoad] in myResults.o

-[myappnameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in myappnameAppDelegate.o

-[myappnameAppDelegate dealloc] in myappnameAppDelegate.o

-[myappnameViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in myappnameViewController.o

-[myResults viewDidLoad] in myResults.o

-[myappnameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in myappnameAppDelegate.o

-[myappnameAppDelegate dealloc] in myappnameAppDelegate.o

-[myappnameViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in myappnameViewController.o

-[myResults viewDidLoad] in myResults.o

Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Where myappname is the name of the app and myResults is the second screen.

I already set "build active architecture only"  to yes, but that didn't do the trick.

gGeboortedatum is a global NSDate variable. I just changed this from NSString to NSDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to go wrong when I habve a global NSDate variable. Changed it to NSString (and then convert it). This works, but isn't nice of course.